# How can I download or save JMeter result on my desktop?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am doing a web based project & took 100 Users, Loop Count: 1 & Ramp Up Period :1 sec for Performance Load Testing of all pages .

There is 500 Samples are showing & i need to make a report of results(of tables & tree) on it.
I can take the Screenshots but its good for few users or few samples.

For 500 or 1000 samples(can not take screenshots for all sample results).
How can I Save or Download the results on my desktop or in any folder? Is there any option?

Help Needed. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some recommendations:

**Don'ts**

1. Don't use View Results Tree and/or View Results Table for anything but test development or debug
2. Don't use JMeter's GUI for real load test
3. Disable all the listeners for performance test run.
4. Follow [JMEter's best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) guidelines

**Do's**

1. Run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) mode as

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl
   ```
2. Once test is finished open JMeter's GUI and add i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener to see results summary. If you're interested in individual requests you still can use View Results in Table or View Results Tree listeners, but in case of View Results Tree you won't be able to see requests/responses details as JMeter doesn't store them in default configuration.
3. Optionally you can use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) to [generate good looking graphs](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) to simplify the process of results analysis and better representation.

Comment: Can i add Aggregate Report in same Test Plan or i have to create test plans & users again ?   @Dmitri

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri ... i got the results ..